# longest duplicate sequences in list

Tags: python

The problem with my code is that it looks for individual elements and not the whole sequence. I am looking for the longest duplicate sequence and the first index of original and the duplicate sequence. Example: input: 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 6 output: 4 2 6, input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 7 8 9 output: 1 4 6

```
input = list(map(int, input().split()))
duple = []
new  = []
lenght = 0
same_duple = []
for elem in input:
    if elem in new:
        duple.append(elem)
    else:
        new.append(elem)

if duple[0] in input:
    index_first = input.index(duple[0]) 

if len(duple) > 1:
    if len(set(duple)) == 1:
        duple.append(duple[0]) 
        lenght = len(duple)//2
        index_sec = (len(input) - list(reversed(input)).index(duple[lenght])-lenght)
        #index_sec = (len(input) - list(reversed(input)).index(same_duple[0])-1)
        #index_sec = next((idx for idx, item in enumerate(input) if item in input[:idx]), None)
    else:
        lenght = len(duple)
        index_sec = (len(vstup) - list(reversed(input)).index(duple[0])-1)
else:
        lenght = len(duple)
        index_sec = (len(vstup) - list(reversed(input)).index(duple[0])-1)

print(lenght)
print(index_first)
print(index_sec)
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74072565/two-longest-indentical-sequences)?

Comment: why would the first input give 4, 2, 6 as output?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a loop? It seems like you are shooting yourself in the foot by using sets both in terms of performance and readability. Plus since sets do not have an ordering, adding/removing an element outside of the longest sequence could change the result of the function if there are multiple values for the longest sequence.

For example, here is how you could get the longest sequence in a list.

```py
def longest_sequence(input):
    if len(input) == 0:
        return 0, 0

    sequence_start = 0
    sequence_length = 1
    current_length = 1
    for index, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(input, input[1:])):
        if first == second:
            current_length += 1
        else:
            current_length = 1

        if current_length > sequence_length:
            sequence_length = current_length
            sequence_start = index - current_length + 1

    return sequence_start, sequence_length
```